# jQuery Mousewheel event prevents page scrolling need solution for that

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-events, mousewheel

```
jQuery('#section-1').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
        jQuery('#section-1-link').click();
    }
    else{
        jQuery('html, body').scroll();
    }
});
jQuery('#section-1').on('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
        jQuery('#section-1-link').click();
    }
    else{
        jQuery(window).scroll();
    }
});
jQuery('#section-1-link').click(function(){
    jQuery('#section-1').slideUp('slow');
    jQuery('#section-2').slideDown('slow');
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery('#section-2').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Above is my jQuery code which I am using to `mousewheel` event to scroll section 1 to 2 and slide them with `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` also attaching screenshot for idea.

[image]

On click of 01, 02, 03 I am sliding three sections which are working fine with `mousewheel` event but it prevents my page to scroll section next or previous to this section.